# Navigation with algin:center

Tags: html-lists, center, nav

i have here a little example side to learn HTML.

This is the HTML part:

```
    <!-- header open -->
 <header role="banner">
 <h1>Beispielaufgaben zu HTML5<br>und CSS3</h1>
  <nav class="clearfix">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="home.html">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="html.html">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="css.html">CSS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
<!-- header close -->
```

This is the CSS part:

```
html {
    margin:0;
    pading:0;
}
.wrapper {
    width:90%;
    max-width:1500px;
    margin-top:2%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    }
header h1 {
    font-size:350%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#999;
    }
nav ul li {
    background-color:#CCC;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    font-size:200%;
    text-align:center;
    }
}
```

I want that the navigation is centered like h1, but i didnt will work with a bunch of testet ways...

anyone knows a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes to the **CSS** and it should do what you want now:

```
html {
    margin:0;
    pading:0;
}
.wrapper {
    width:90%;
    max-width:1500px;
    margin-top:2%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    }
header h1 {
    font-size:350%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#999;
    }
nav ul li {
    background-color:#CCC;
    display:block; /*Changed to display: inline-block to replace float*/
    float:left; /*Removed because would interfere with added text-align on nav*/
    width:20%;
    font-size:200%;
    text-align:center; /*Removed because not needed*/
    }
} /*Removed random closing curly bracket*/
nav {
    text-align: center; /*Added to align all <li> in center*/
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U6Khy/1/